# How to debug rails app Ruby 2.1.3, Rails 4 with sublime text

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi can anyone share with me his best practice of debugging rails app?? There is a lot of debugging gems on the web. but some of them are not working with 2.1.3 and some of them are not comfortable to use.

Comment: I tried to re-open this question as I found an answer which would help many people I believe.  The plugin to do as the question states is found here: https://github.com/shuky19/sublime_debugger

Answer (score 3):

- You need a decent REPL to try out code samples. [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/) is good enough.
- For Rails to invoke `pry` instead of `irb` as a console, use [`pry-rails`](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails)
- You need a debugger. You could use [Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug), a `debugger` gem replacement for MRI Ruby 2
- You can tie the two above with [`pry-byebug`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) and have line-by-line stepping through code wherever you run `binding.pry`
- You can get live syntax highlighting as you type with a [`pry-coolline` gem](https://github.com/pry/pry-coolline)

All this has nothing to do with Sublime Text though.

Answer (score 1):

RubyMine 7 has great debugging features if you're unable to get the results you want with Sublime. Which is more of an intermediate to expert level editor, not an official IDE to support the environment you want. It's basically for Ruby developers who understand the process completely.